# Stuck in getting calculations of transaction values

Tags: sql-server

I have an event table and want to do calculations on the basis on most recent transaction values.

```
create table evt (evnt integer not null,
value integer not null,
time datetime not null,
)
```

and query:

```
SELECT evnt ,value
FROM evt where time IN (select max(time) from events group by evnt )
   GROUP BY evnt ,value

insert into evt values (2,5,'2018-05-09 12:42:00')
insert into evt values (4,-42,'2018-05-09 13:19:57')
insert into evt values (2,2,'2018-05-09 14:48:30')
insert into evt values (2,7,'2018-05-09 12:54:39')
insert into evt values (3,16,'2018-05-09 13:19:57')
insert into evt values (3,20,'2018-05-09 15:01:09')
```

Output

```
evnt    |   Value
-------------------
2       |  -5
3       |   4
```

[image]

Comment: What Calculations you have to do ? And in the Output how did you get value as -5 ?

Comment: For the evnt 2, the latest value is 2 and the second latest value is 7. so the difference between them is -5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your brief description, i guess this is what you wanted

```
select  evnt, sum(case when rn = 1 then value else -value end)
from
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by evnt order by time desc)
    from    evt
) d
where   d.rn    <= 2
group by evnt
having  count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Can we achieve it without row_number()?

Comment: any particular reason you want to avoid `row_number` ?

Comment: so you are allow to use ?

Comment: Can't use row_number() .